# WebView[styleClass=root web-view]is already set as root of another scene

Tags: java, javafx, spring-boot, webview

Я использую библиотеку WeaverFX, которая позволяет инъектить Javafx контекст внутрь SpringBoot контекста и также использую PDFViewr чтобы загружать PDF документы из массива байт в визуальное представление на сцене. Когда я пытаюсь сменить сцену в LibraryController (причем в первый раз PDF показывается нормально и никаких исключений не вызывается) я получаю исключение "WebView[styleClass=root web-view]is already set as root of another scene"

Ниже в LibraryController я прокомментировал как я пытаюсь установить сцену используя WeaverFX и PDFviewer, сначала вместе, а потом только используя PDFViewer

WeaverFX lib - https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver

PDFViewer lib - https://github.com/Dansoftowner/PDFViewerFX

**BaseController**

```
import com.dansoftware.pdfdisplayer.PDFDisplayer;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Slf4j
public abstract class BaseController {
    @Autowired private Stage stage;

    public void setScene(Button button, String title, Class controller, FxWeaver fxWeaver) {
        try {
            button.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Parent root = (Parent) fxWeaver.loadView(controller);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unexpected exception while setting scene   " + e);
        }
    }

    public void setScene(Hyperlink link, String title, Class controller, FxWeaver fxWeaver) {
        try {
            link.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Parent root = (Parent) fxWeaver.loadView(controller);
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unexpected exception while setting scene  " + e);
        }
    }

    public void setScene(String title, PDFDisplayer displayer, FxWeaver fxWeaver) {
        try {
            Parent root = (Parent) fxWeaver.loadView(displayer.toNode().getClass()); ---HERE I'M TRIED TO USE WEAVERFX+PDFVIEWER BUT GET NOSUCHBEANEXCEPTION
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unexpected exception while setting scene  " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**LibraryController**

```
import com.dansoftware.pdfdisplayer.PDFDisplayer;
import com.library.client.service.AlertService;
import com.library.client.service.FileUploadService;
import com.library.client.service.dto.BookDTO;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxmlView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@FxmlView("/FXML/library.fxml")
public class LibraryController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired private FxWeaver fxWeaver;
    @Autowired private WebClient webClient;
    @Autowired private PDFDisplayer displayer;

    @FXML private ScrollBar dataScroll;
    @FXML private Button backButton;
    @FXML private Button deletingButton;
    @FXML private TableView<BookDTO> libTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<BookDTO, Long> id;
    @FXML private TableColumn<BookDTO, String> title;
    @FXML private TableColumn<BookDTO, String> author;
    @FXML private TableColumn<BookDTO, String> publishDate;

    private final AlertService alertService;
    private final FileUploadService fileUploadService;


    public LibraryController(AlertService alertService,
                             FileUploadService fileUploadService) {
        this.alertService = alertService;
        this.fileUploadService = fileUploadService;
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        List<BookDTO> booksList = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:10120/book/get")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BookDTO>>() {
                })
                .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error when trying to send request to server - [{}]", exception.getMessage()))
                .block();

        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BookDTO, Long>("id"));
        author.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BookDTO, String>("author"));
        title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BookDTO, String>("title"));
        publishDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BookDTO, String>("publishDate"));

        libTable.getItems().addAll(booksList);

        libTable.setRowFactory(
                tableView -> {
                    TableRow<BookDTO> row = new TableRow<>();
                    row.setOnMouseClicked(
                            event -> {
                                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                                    byte[] bytesOfBook = webClient.get()
                                            .uri("http://localhost:10120/book/get-bytes/" + row.getItem().getId())
                                            .retrieve()
                                            .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
                                            .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error when trying to send request to serve - [{}]", exception.getMessage()))
                                            .block();
                                        try {
--TRYING TO USE ONLY PDFVIEWER
                                            Stage stage = new Stage();
                                            displayer.loadPDF(fileUploadService.convertToFile(bytesOfBook));
                                            Parent root = displayer.toNode();
                                            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                                            stage.setTitle("Lib");
                                            stage.setResizable(false);
                                            stage.setScene(scene);
                                            stage.show();
   ---CALL SERVICE WHICH TRIED TO USE WEAVERFX+PDFVIEWER TOGETHER
                                            setScene("Lib", displayer, fxWeaver);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return row;
                    });
        }
    }
```

**BookDTO**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class BookDTO {
    long id;
    String title;
    String author;
    LocalDate publishDate;
    String owner;
    byte[] fileData;
}
```

**AlertService**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AlertService {
    public Optional<ButtonType> showAlert(Alert.AlertType type, String title, String content, boolean NeedToReturnResult) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(type);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setContentText(content);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (NeedToReturnResult) return result;
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FileUploadService**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class FileUploadService {
    private final AlertService alertService;

    public FileUploadService(AlertService alertService) {
        this.alertService = alertService;
    }

    public File convertToFile(byte[] book) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File("C:/temp/books");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            try {
                folder.mkdirs();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                log.error("Can't create output catalog because has not permission");
                alertService.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,
                        "Error",
                        "Error",
                        false);
            }
        }
        Path filepath = Paths.get("C:/temp/books" + File.separator + "out.pdf");
        if (Files.exists(filepath)) {
            Files.delete(filepath);
        }
        Files.write(Files.createFile(filepath), book);
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(filepath));
        return file;
    }
}
```

**ClientApplication**

```
public class ClientApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .sources(StartJavaFX.class)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FxWeaver fxWeaver = context.getBean(FxWeaver.class);
        Parent root = fxWeaver.loadView(LibraryController.class);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Main menu");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        this.context.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

**StartJavaFX**

```
import com.dansoftware.pdfdisplayer.PDFDisplayer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.spring.SpringFxWeaver;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StartJavaFX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FxWeaver fxWeaver(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new SpringFxWeaver(applicationContext);
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public PDFDisplayer getPDF() {
        return new PDFDisplayer();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public Stage getStage() {
        return new Stage();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public WebClient createWebClient() {
        return WebClient.create();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>

        <spring.boot.version>2.6.1</spring.boot.version>
        <thymeleaf-spring5.version>3.1.0.M1</thymeleaf-spring5.version>
        <jackson.version>2.12.2</jackson.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.weaver.version>1.3.0</javafx.weaver.version>
        <javafx.pdfviewer.version>0.8</javafx.pdfviewer.version>
        <springdoc.swagger.version>1.5.13</springdoc.swagger.version>
        <unirest.version>1.4.9</unirest.version>
        <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.11.0</commons.io.version>
        <spring.test.version>5.3.16</spring.test.version>


        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.0.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- JavaFX PDFViewer -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- web flux -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx -->
        <!-- javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-weaver starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.weaver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-weaver core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-core</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.weaver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaFX PDFViewer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.Dansoftowner</groupId>
            <artifactId>PDFViewerFX</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.pdfviewer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.library.client.StartJavaFX</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

**library.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.library.client.frontend.LibraryController">
   <children>
      <StackPane layoutX="99.0" layoutY="177.0" prefHeight="426.0" prefWidth="1087.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="libTable" prefHeight="446.0" prefWidth="1159.0">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="57.0" text="Id" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="title" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="442.0" text="Title" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="author" prefWidth="231.0" text="Author" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="publishDate" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="343.0" text="Publish date" />
               </columns>
            </TableView>
            <ScrollBar fx:id="dataScroll" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="14.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Stacktrace when using only displayer**

```
2022-03-29 17:34:27.962  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-29 17:34:28.445  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-29 17:34:28.453  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-29 17:34:28.454  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-03-29 17:34:28.516  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-29 17:34:28.516  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 533 ms
2022-03-29 17:34:29.005  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-29 17:34:29.013  INFO 3608 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Started application in 1.259 seconds (JVM running for 2.018)
PDF 23fa3cab1a65ceae12b031b329ee254d [1.4 Skia/PDF m93 / Chromium] (PDF.js: 2.7.570)
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebView@42bc3eb2[styleClass=root web-view]is already set as root of another scene
    at javafx.scene.Scene$8.invalidated(Scene.java:1216)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1178)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:356)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:207)
    at com.library.client.frontend.LibraryController.lambda$initialize$2(LibraryController.java:87)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3563)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3865)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
PDF 23fa3cab1a65ceae12b031b329ee254d [1.4 Skia/PDF m93 / Chromium] (PDF.js: 2.7.570)
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
Warning: Failed to load font 'normal': 'NetworkError:  A network error occurred.'.
```

**And stacktrace when I'm trying to use weaverFx+PDFViewer together**

```
2022-03-29 17:35:38.960  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-29 17:35:39.447  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-29 17:35:39.456  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-29 17:35:39.456  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-03-29 17:35:39.518  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-29 17:35:39.518  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 537 ms
2022-03-29 17:35:40.005  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-29 17:35:40.013  INFO 19628 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Started application in 1.259 seconds (JVM running for 2.016)
2022-03-29 17:35:42.711 ERROR 19628 --- [lication Thread] c.l.c.f.BaseController                   : Unexpected exception while setting scene  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javafx.scene.web.WebView' available
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `WebView[styleClass=root web-view]is already set as root of another scene` возникает в этой строке `Scene scene = new Scene(root);` при повторном вызове.

Внутри `PDFDisplayer` для отображения pdf файла [используется](https://github.com/Dansoftowner/PDFViewerFX/blob/5793e1d7a4bb0b1364e82cc3e0f1e9d5993b0394/src/main/java/com/dansoftware/pdfdisplayer/PDFDisplayer.java#L41) `WebView` и метод [`toNode()`](https://github.com/Dansoftowner/PDFViewerFX/blob/5793e1d7a4bb0b1364e82cc3e0f1e9d5993b0394/src/main/java/com/dansoftware/pdfdisplayer/PDFDisplayer.java#L291) не создаёт каждый раз объект WebView: для кадого `PDFDisplayer` свой один `WebView`.

Попробуйте для каждого нового окна просмотра использовать отдельный `PDFDisplayer`.